# Avoid prepending id on custom component's inner elements

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I am refactoring an existing codebase to use composite components. A lot of the existing logic uses the id on the element. As soon as I extract some html into a custom component and give it an id X, then the id on the inner html changes to 
X:id. 
Is there a way to avoid the custom component id getting prepended onto the inner html elements? i.e if I have a table in the custom component with id Y, I want the final html to have an id of Y on that table, not X:Y.

Comment: Just use the right tool for the job.

Comment: @BalusC thanks for the links, I went through all of them. Am still convinced that what I need is the composite component. Basically a certain page has a text box and associated dropdown repeated for many fields. I want to make that into a single reusable component to which I pass parameters like id, etc. But that id parameter is getting rewritten to compositeCompnentId: myid.

Comment: It does that to ensure uniqueness of IDs when multiple of them are used in the same page. If you disable it, you can't use multiple of them in the same page. Moreover, the client shouldn't care about composite's internals. If it need to do, your composite most certainly shouldn't be a composite at all.

Comment: I changed it to use the facelets tag file and that works much better for my case. Thanks.